# How to add newline after a repeating pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume that there is a string like this:

```
var content = "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20";
```

I want to add `<br />` after every 5 dots.

So, the result should be:

```
1.2.3.4.5.<br />
6.7.8.9.10.<br />
11.12.13.14.15.<br />
16.17.18.19.20.<br />
```

I want to do this without a `for` loop. Is it possible with just regex?

i'm doing this with this code;

```
regenerate:function(content,call){
    var data2;
    var brbr = content.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, '').match(/(\r\n)/g);
    if (brbr !== "") {
      data2 = content.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, '').replace(/(\r\n)/gm, "<br><br>");
    } else {
      data2 = content.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, '');
    }
    var dataArr = data2.split(".");

    for (var y = 10; y < dataArr.length - 10; y += 10) {
      var dataArrSpecific1 = dataArr[y] + ".";
      var dataArrSpecific2 = dataArr[y] + ".<br>";
      var dataArrSpecificBosluk = dataArr[y + 1];
      var data3 = data2.replace(new RegExp(dataArrSpecific1.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, ''), "g"), "" + dataArrSpecific2.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, '') + "");
      data3 = data3.replace(new RegExp(dataArrSpecificBosluk.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, ''), "g"), "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + dataArrSpecificBosluk.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, '') + "");
      data2 = data3;
    }
    call(data2.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, ''));
  }
```

Actually , i want to refactoring this code

Comment: Everyone wants something but we need to work to it. So what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions to insert "\r" every n characters in a line and before a complete word (basically a wordwrap feature)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232603/regular-expressions-to-insert-r-every-n-characters-in-a-line-and-before-a-com)

Comment: it looks like similar but it is not . Can we know that 5 dot and add br after that every 5th dot with just regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working bin:http://jsbin.com/dikifipelo/1/

```
var string = "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20." ;   

string = string.replace(/(([^\.]+\.){5})/g, "$1<br/>");
```

Works with any type and length of characters between the dots.

**Explanation**:
The pattern `/(([^.]+.){5})/g` can be broken down as such:

- `[^\.]` - any character that is not a dot
- `[^\.]+` - any character that is not a dot, one or more times
- `[^\.]+\.` - any character that is not a dot, one or more times, followed by a dot
- `([^\.]+\.){5}` - any character....dot, appearing five times
- `(([^\.]+\.){5})` - any...five times, capture this (all round brackets capture unless told not to, with a ?: as the first thing inside them)
  the `/g/` flag makes it so that the whole string is matched - ie, all matches are found
- `"$1"` represents the results of the first group (or bracket)
  so, the replace function finds all instances of the pattern in the string, and replaces them with the match itself + a line break (`br`).

Once you learn regular expressions, life is never the same.

Comment: Yes , it is working , thank you very much bro :) , i think , if someone do not know an answer of question , he should not write worthless words :)

Comment: Added an explanation, hope that helps too!

Comment: Yes , you amazing , really it is true , 15 lines of code is 2 lines of code now :D